# Getting Spaces instead of text in Pdf generated through Jrxml Template

Tags: jasper-reports, export-to-pdf

I am generating a Pdf Report using jrxml template. In local machine pdf is genereated properly but when deployed in dev, For some of the field last 1 or 2 words are not getting displayed instead space is generated at that place.

Pdf On Dev Environment:
[image: Pdf on Dev Env]

Pdf On local machine:
[image: Pdf On local machine]

jRXML code for the same is as follows:

```
        <staticText>
            <reportElement uuid="2eb3283e-a9be-40a2-9096-5ff312b18ed7" x="44" y="103" width="313" height="20">
                <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$V{PAGE_NUMBER}==1]]></printWhenExpression>
            </reportElement>
            <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                <font fontName="Arial" size="11"/>
            </textElement>
            <text><![CDATA[Previous year (P.Y.) (for which declaration is being made)   :]]></text>
        </staticText>
```

Can anybody please help me in understanding why it's behaving differently in different environment.

Comment: Looks like font issue. BTW, images looks similar

Comment: @AlexK My bad. Updated the images now.

Comment: You can compare two lists of embedded fonts (for example with help of Foxit Reader, Properties -> Fonts) from two pdf files you generated

Comment: @AlexK I have compared. In both pdf its saying font is "Helvetica" and "Helvetica-Bold " but not embedded. there is no difference i can see as Font.